# Jquery passing the retrieved value to another id

Tags: jquery

This is my first day using Jquery, I want to retrieve the id from the clicked element and pass the id to another element. So far I know that the id fetch is working fine according to my code, but I'm unable pass the value to another element! Idk where I'm going wrong.
Here is the code.

```
$(function() {
    $(".prs").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x= $(this).get(0).id);
        $("span #x").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

I want to pass the retrieved id to the id of span as in last line of code.

Comment: use `$("span #"+x).slideToggle("slow");` hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jQuery, it's a JavaScript matter. You need to concatenate the string and your variable. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".prs").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x= $(this).get(0).id);
        $("span #" + x).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

However, just a side note. You don't need jQuery to get the `id`. Simply use JavaScript like this:

```
var x= this.id;
```

So your code can be simplified like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".prs").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("span #" + this.id).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Finally, just a comment about the ids, it's not valid HTML to have two items with the same id. So you'll have to give them different ids, let say `my_object` for the clickable element and `my_oject_box` for the span. Then your code becomes:

```
$(function() {
    $(".prs").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#" + this.id + "_box").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
$(function() {
  $(".prs").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var x= $(this).attr('id');
      $("span #" + x).slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x= $(this).get(0).id; 
$("span#"+x).slideToggle("slow")
```

$("span#"+x) is to access the same span 
$("span #"+x) is to access element with that id within the span but I think it is not good practice to have two elements having same id.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I see that you are triggering slide animation on same element (since ID is unique in page and there can't be to same ID elements) as you clicked so you can do like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $(".prs").click(function() {
      $(this).slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id-1" class="prs">ID-1</div>
<div id="id-2" class="prs">ID-2</div>
```

---

To trigger slide from other element you can use data attribute to have it as target (`data-target="..."` = `$.data('target')`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('button').click(function () {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).slideToggle('slow');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id-1">ID-1</div>
<div id="id-2">ID-2</div>
<hr/>
<button data-target="#id-1">Turn on/off #1</button>
<button data-target="#id-2">Turn on/off #2</button>
```

Comment: span is different element!  not the same on from where i'm accepting id

Comment: @JIMMY `$(this).get(0).id; $("span #" + id)` is showing to same element. Also you do not provide any HTML structure.